# Transforming a date to a day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server, can someone please show me how to write a query to display what day of the week someone was hired. Can someone show me an example for admin richard wiley. According to the info he was hired on Friday.

```
CREATE TABLE STAFF (
    sID int PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstN varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    LastN varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Title varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    DateHired date NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (5, 'Richard', 'Wiley', 'Admin', '2020-02-12')
```

Thanks!

Comment: use `DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [DateHired])`

Comment: Please do your research - you would come across the date function `datepart()` and `datename()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get this.

```sql
-- Using Datename function
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY,DateHired) AS day_name from dbo.STAFF where sid = 5;
GO

-- Using Format function
SELECT FORMAT(DateHired,'dddd') AS day_name from dbo.STAFF where sid = 5;
GO

--Another approach is set first day as Monday for the session and get the value
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Setting datefirst as monday
SELECT 
CASE DATEPART(dw,DateHired) 
WHEN 1 THEN 'Monday'
WHEN 2 THEN 'Tuesday'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Wednesday'
WHEN 4 THEN 'Thursday'
WHEN 5 THEN 'Friday'
WHEN 6 THEN 'Saturday'
WHEN 7 THEN 'Sunday' end AS day_name from dbo.STAFF where sid = 5;
GO
```

| day_name |
| --- |
| Wednesday |